# Rails 4 XML to HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, render

I'm new to Rails and trying to render a given XML file as HTML in my view. I've searched for some time now but I could only find topics on how to render XML as HTML. I'm not planning to do anything fancy, just style the output a little bit in CSS. Is there some obvious solution to this in Rails I'm missing?

It would be useful to have an output I could work with like with a db request result, for example:

```
@titles.each do |title|
  title.author
  title.date
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you add the `ruby` tag to your question, you'll get people giving you advise on [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/). I don't have experience with it

Comment: Do you wants to send response in xml ?

Comment: I'm sorry I just noticed I had edited my question wrong. I updated it so it should now be more correct and detailed. @Bharatsoni no I want to render a XML response from an other site like it was from my own db.

Comment: You should provide an additional block with the kind of XML you would like to parse. That way people have something to start with. Like this the question is to vague to write any code as an answer. Btw: Stackoverflow showed [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823/xml-html-with-hpricot-and-rails?rq=1) as related, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Nokogiri which has an XML parser. Let's say you're using some API to get a XML response, then you could do something like this:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(your_api_url))
items = Hash.from_xml(xml.to_xml)
```

note: you need to call .to_xml on the xml var because before that, it's an Nokogiri object.

`items` is now a Ruby hash. You could now for example build a Ruby object out of it which you can then use like every other ActiveRecord object. If it's more than one `entry`, it could be useful to save all items in an array:

```
@all_items = Array.new

items['item'].map do |item|
  new = Item.new
  new.title = item['title‘]
  # an so on..

  @all_items << new
end
```

Now, in your view, you could do this:

```
<% @all_items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.title %>
<% end %>
```

To make this work as above, you need these two gems:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
```

I hope that helps!